# MSN messenger type popup notification using classic visual basic 6.0

Tags: vb6

How to build MSN messenger type popup notification using classic Visual Basic 6.0?

Comment: hi people,

i just found one excellent source code for the above requirement. Here is the link http://www.vbforums.com/showthread.php?t=320639. Take Care

Comment: Its ok to add an answer to your own question, the above comment is actually the answer.  You should add it and after a couple of days with no one else blazing in with a really amazing answer you should accept your answer.

Answer (score 1):

I just found one excellent [source code for the above requirement](http://www.vbforums.com/showthread.php?320639-MSN-Messenger-Style-Systray-Notification-Messages).